# MySQL Query to get a list of events with at least 3 different status?

Tags: mysql

I have a database containing two tables :

**Events** `(id, name, is_active)`

**Event_logs** `(id, event_id, status, message)`

I'd like to list all the events that had at least 3 different `status` logs in it and is still active (`is_active=1`) and I can't come up with the correct `MySQL` query to do that.

(I can add more details if needed, just ask :) ).

Here's the SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7442

In that example, I'm looking to get the event ID 2 because it contains 3 different status in event_log : INFO, WARNING and ERROR.
Event ID 1 and 3 contains less than 3 and so are excluded.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm asking. Consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. 14.3k? How did that happen?

Comment: I'm quite certain I am overthinking this and so I'm stuck in this way. I'm pretty sure it's easy, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I've updated the description to include the fiddle, maybe it will help better understand my problem.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm stuck at how I can get event IDs from event_log containg 3 **DIFFERENT** status, not `count(l.status)` from @Utsav answer below. It's the distinction I can't get correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe more coffee is required...

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM events e
  JOIN event_logs l
    ON l.event_id = e.id
 WHERE is_active=1 
 GROUP 
    BY e.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l.status) >=3
```

Comment: ... or maybe I didn't knew about COUNT(DISTINCT ..). Thank you for your help.

Comment: perfect. I wasn't able to open the fiddle so thanks for stepping in :)

Comment: ...hence my previous comment!

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test but if I understand the requirement correctly, this should work

```
select e.id , l.status
from events e 
inner join event_logs l
on e.id=l.event_id
where l.is_active=1
group by e.id,l.status
having count(*) >=3
```

Comment: Thank you for your query. The result returns a list of event id where event_logs occurent more than 3 times, but it contains some events that have the same status 5 times. I'm looking to list the events where the logs contaings 3 differents status. I'm sorry if it's not clear : I'm going to add the `INSERT` and expected result.

Comment: @CyrilN. So just be a little more specific about what it is you're counting. This isn't difficult, and a cursory examination of COUNT within the manual would reveal the answer.

Comment: `but it contains some events that have the same status 5 times` To avoid it, I already put `l.status` in `group by`. Anyways giving sample data and expected output would help in understanding it better.

Comment: I've updated my question with a SQLFiddle, Hopefully, it will be more clear?

Comment: I believe the solution is not with `having count(l.status) >= 3` but to get where there is at leats 3 different `status` in each event id. This is the part I'm stuck finding.